# Word TOC Has One Indent Larger Than The Rest

Tags: microsoft-word, formatting, table-of-contents, indentation, autoindent

I'm having a problem with the TOC in a word document where one indent is twice as big as all the other ones. There is no extra indent in the heading which I initially thought was the problem. I have a picture of what the TOC looks like: [Messed Up TOC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jHn7.png). Does anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that the first line indent is not set in the corresponding paragraph heading.

In addition, please make sure you don’t set this header as a secondary title

Answer (score 0):

You may note that the "M" is slightly wider than the other characters used. This (with the full stop) pushes it just past the area allowed prior to the first tab setting in the TOC Style. You need to widen that area, just a bit by moving the tab setting in the style.

If you have the Ruler displayed, click in the problem line in your Table of Contents, and move the first tab stop just a bit to the right, until the text moves back closer. Then click on a different line and they should all line up.

Here is a link to MVP Suzanne Barnhill's work on the Table of Contents.[enter link description here](http://wordfaqs.ssbarnhill.com/TOCTips.htm#IndentsTabs)